# I am getting error in my DataSnapShot in getuserinformation

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, snapshot

**here is the code**

```
     static void getCurrentOnlineUserInformation()async{
  User user = _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
  String userid = user.uid;
  DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('userProfile');
  reference.child(userid).once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
  }
  );
  }
```

**but its not fetching DataSnapShot**

**Error**
error: The argument type 'Null Function(DataSnapshot)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr Function(DatabaseEvent)'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [themovers] lib\assistants\assistantmethods.dart:86)

its getting null value again and again

[here is live code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7e8ku.png)

[here is database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxeTG.png)

[here is the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IsAk.png)

Answer (score 0):

By default .then accepts dynamic `parameter` but if you wish to pass different `parameter` then you have change `Function(dynamic)` to `Function(YOURTYPE)` try below code:

```
static void getCurrentOnlineUserInformation()async{
  User user = _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
  String userid = user.uid;
  DatabaseReference reference = 
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('userProfile');
         reference.child(userid).once().then(<DataSnapshot>(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        }
      );
  }
```

Comment: getting same error again and showing this bar now The argument type 'Null Function<DataSnapshot>(DataSnapshot)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<dynamic> Function(DatabaseEvent)'